# Adding many markers using leaflet slows down browser

Tags: javascript, performance, leaflet

Adding many markers(10000) using leaflet is slowing down the browser.
markers are moving after every 5 sec.
How can performance issue solved in such scenario.
Note : Clustermarker has one problem. It's difficult to keep track of moving marker.

Answer (score 0):

I'd the same issue, I bypassed it because 1000 markers is too much information.

I put two events:

1. On specific zoom level, I query my database to have (less) markers. In argument i give the map's coordinates [like this example](http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/examples/0000-viewer.html#/basic/bounds-example). Tips: i add +1 and -1 on lat and lng to anticipate step 2
2. I've got an event `leafletDirectiveMap.mooveend`. When this event is call, I'm doing the step 1. Tips: I'd $timeout with 300ms on this events.

If you need to show all markers, maybe using the heatmaps layer on specific zoom is an another bypass.

Sorry if it's not the solution of your problem but, iIf you try [this example](http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/examples/0000-viewer.html#/markers/clustering-10000-markers-example), you can see 10000 markers slowdown browser.

Comment: Thanks. But markers are always atleast 10000 or more than this number

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [`L.marker()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#marker)?  I've had better performance results with [`L.divIcon()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#divicon).

Alternatively, you could draw your markers directly on the canvas (as is done in [`Leaflet MaskCanvas`](https://github.com/domoritz/leaflet-maskcanvas)).  You can also update markers that are drawn on the canvas.  Note: this isn't a plug-and-play suggestion; you'll have to do some coding to make this idea work.

Here are some other ideas from this [GIS StackExchange question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34589/visualizing-large-datasets-with-leaflet) and [this other GIS StackExchange question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227868/high-performance-markers-on-leaflet-map/).

Comment: I tried both L.marker and L.divIcon. There was not much improvement.